# Element shown with JavaScript displays incorrectly for IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have an element that is set to display none on page load. When you select a number from a select list the element is shown with jQuery. This works fine in all browsers except in IE7.

In IE7 everything is laid out correctly if I disable JavaScript. However with js turned on (and then the element shown via the select list) the legend appears in the wrong place. If with the developer tools I change the width of the fieldset and change it back to the original value, then it displays correctly.

So it seems like its some sort of rendering issue for hidden elements in IE7. If I add this CSS it messes my site but it fixed this particular issue.

```
* {
position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: IE7 has some crazy bugs regarding positioning of elements. To help, I'd need to see the HTML and CSS or see the live page.

Comment: I cant really expose my code. When I change any CSS property to the legend or its containing elements and change it back the design snaps to how it should be (how it looks with js disabled). So, it seems it must be a rendering issue. Is there a way to force IE to re-render or similar an element? A js solution would be fine as the issue only occurs when js is enabled in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class which is hidden with css rather than adding display none as an inline style fixed this.